# inAPP purchase testing procedure

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm going crazy testing my app for inApp purchase. I cannot get any valid product.

I'll try to make some questions here, hope someone could answer.

1. Do I have to upload the binary of my test app on iTunes connect? My app has never been published in app store, it's a brand new app just in test.
2. If I have to upload binary, I upload a Distribution signed binary. NOW, do I have to use the same binary (Distribution signed) on my tests? Or I can use a developer binary?
3. I've checked many and many times all critical and known problems like boundle ID, taxes info, Clear for sale checkbox and all these things. They are all ok.
4. After adding an iAP product, it is marked "Waiting for Review", is this correct or I should wait it change state before I can see it as valid?

Answer (score 5):

There is no need what-so-ever to submit the application binary before testing in-app-purchase in SANDBOX environment.

The In-App-Purchase product'll 've state READY TO SUBMIT.[image]

Comment: @Rose No knowledge on how things work on goggle play...this is w.r.t. iOS

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem.
for me helped 2 things in combination:

1. remove "rejected" status via uploading the binaries again
2. don't use a jailbroken device

But in FAQ 6 are some more reasons for this problem listed:

- You did not complete all the financial requirements (see the "Contracts, Tax, and Banking Information" section of this document).
- You did not use an explicit App ID.
- You did not use the Provisioning Profile associated with your explicit App ID.
- You did not use the correct product identifier in your code. See Technical Q&A, QA1329, 'In App Purchase Product Identifiers' for more information about product identifiers.
- You did not clear your In App Purchase products for sale in iTunes Connect.
- You might have modified your products, but these changes are not yet available to all the App Store servers.
- If you or App Review rejected your most recent binary in iTunes Connect.

hope this will help some more of you.

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother with all of the voodoo suggestions surrounding in-app purchases, the official Apple [Technical Note TN2259](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html) describes all the steps in detail... and it works.

Comment: This document (and the IAP FAQ that it links to: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2413/_index.html) are the missing links for this whole process.  Why the documentation itself can't be this clear and direct is both a mystery and a travesty.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to upload a binary.  You can set up your app in iTunes Connect, and then set up your products associated with it.  The "Waiting For Review" on your products will stay waiting for review until you submit a binary and submit the app and it gets approved.  You can still test, however, even with your products "Waiting For Review".  There is (IIRC) a transitional state which you as developer must mark your products as approved after you have tested them.

Note: Once you create the app in iTunes Connect, you have 90 days to submit a binary before they take your app name away from you.

Note 2: When testing with your debug build before submission, you have to use the development sandbox servers.  See the IAP documentation for more info.

Comment: So based on what you say and what i did, i should have the product list working, unfortunately does not work. Could be possibile I have to wait hours or days before the products become available for testing? I've read this on many other forums.

Comment: Do I only need to logout from itunes store account to use sandbox servers? This is what I understand from IAP documentation.

Comment: with the new SDK (beta) because of the iCloud stuff its very difficult to actually log your iPhone out of your iTunes account.  But now the storekit is supported on the simulator!!  try it ;)   unless you are not in the dev program of course...
you ought try my suggestion, I'm pretty confident your problem is in your provisioning profile

Comment: I really hate Apple for dev. The things are just too complicated and just does not work as the documentation describes. Unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 1):

I spent waay too much time on this exact problem too..
you do not need to upload a binary to get the in app purchase testing, what that means in iTunes connect there is that you cant add additional products to an existing product on the iTunes shelves. For example if your app is live and at version 1.0, and v1.0 was submitted with only one in app purchase connected with it, there can never be a 2nd in app product for v1.0, to add a 2nd (or many more) in app products you need to resubmit, go up to 1.01 or whatever.  The key thing that I was overlooking, and I hope this helps, is YOU MUST BE USING A PROVISIONING PROFILE FOR THAT IS MADE FOR THE APP IN QUESTION, not the generic profile that xCode's little helper wizard thing just builds stuff on by default.   Try that

Comment: ++ and make sure you have your app ID filled out correctly in your appInfo.plist too huh

Comment: +10. This got me. Is it possible that valid products are returned if either <You have a non-generic development provisioning profile> or <Your app version status is Developer Rejected>? That seems to be my case...

Answer (score 0):

Those of you having trouble with In-App Purchase (IAP) make sure a few things are done correct,

- create your app in iTunes as you do for release
- setup In-App Purchase (supply everything including screenshot)
- create test users (very important as you cannot use a real user to test while in Sandbox)
- go to your app View Details and make sure you see the In-App entry that you've setup show up there, if not "edit" that section to choose the appropriate In-App entry (very important)
- click on "Ready to upload binary" button (again, very important). Don't worry about uploading binary at that time as you have 90 days from then to upload your binary.
- implement IAP in your code (there are many samples out there, I prefer http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2012/04/implementing-inapp-purchase-in-xcode.html)
- if you are testing it on a device make sure to signout (Settings > iTunes & App Store > Signout (very, very important)

Once all these are done you should be able to make In-App purchases using those test accounts. It worked after a few hair pull-offs for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the project ***Bundle ID*** is the same as the registered for the application in itunesconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying test before release my application...
that was happened to me...

-My in app purchase product was ready to to submit. But I could not get fetch request. could not tested.

-**When,firstly i archive my app, I could start testing...**

So archiving up required to  test in app purchase

Answer (score -1):

Setting up In-App purchases for the first time is a huge headache. I believe that you do need to submit a binary in iTunes Connect. Just submit it and then "developer reject" it right away. If it doesn't work then, wait a few hours or a day and then see if it works. Also, make sure that you check off "Cleared for Sale" for your In-App purchase in iTunes Connect.

EDIT: You should submit a distribution binary but may continue to test with your development binary.

Comment: Submitting and then rejecting just does not make any sense.

Comment: This is the tutorial I used and he says "You must submit a binary for your application in order to successfully test in-app purchases." It worked for me, so it should work for you http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Comment: I seem to remember for me that it didn't work right away. Maybe just check again tomorrow and see if it works. Let us know how that goes :).