# Is it possible to add an in-app purchase to an app without updating the app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing an iOS app that will allow purchase of various additional "Packs" of information as non-consumable purchases, and I intend to add new "Packs" regularly.  (This is my first app, so experience is limited.) My current design simply checks for in-app purchases with product id's "...Pack01" to "...Pack99", and those that it finds are included in the store front.  My assumption has been that after the app is released I can add a new in-app purchase with product id, say "...Pack32" in iTunes Connect, and this will then show up in the store front as soon as it's available.  I don't want to distribute a new update of the app every time I add a new pack.
However I am not sure it's possible to add new in-app purchases without updating the app.  Can someone confirm, please, whether it is possible, and if not, is there another way to achieve the goal of updating the available purchases without distributing new app versions?

Comment: If you design your code well enough, for example, the IAP list wasn't hard coded in the app but fetched from your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible as long as your app can properly deal with the additional products without the need for any new code.

Comment: So iTunes Connect will allow me to add a new IAP? A couple of comments, particularly the third answer here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757464/inapp-purchase-testing-procedure  led me to believe otherwise.

Comment: That question is about testing in-app purchases before an app is approved. That's not your case at all.

Comment: Yes, but the third answer includes this: "you cant add additional products to an existing product on the iTunes shelves. For example if your app is live and at version 1.0, and v1.0 was submitted with only one in app purchase connected with it, there can never be a 2nd in app product for v1.0, to add a 2nd (or many more) in app products you need to resubmit, go up to 1.01 or whatever."  That's what worried me.

Comment: I don't believe that is correct. Once your app and 1st set of IAP is live, you can add additional IAPs without submitting an app update. See the FAQ on iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thanks maddy, I feel reassured.