# iOs adding iAps dynamically

Tags: ios

I'm developing a system where the user(owner of apps) will be able to add iAps dynamically without to resubmit an update.Google Play(Android) is not making any issues ,but since I'm staring out with iOs to do the same things i have came across few issues.

I have seen that there are waiting times for each iAp, and before i start digging more into it i wanted to see will i lose my time on this.

> So am i able to add new iAps without actually making a new update?

The idea behind is that the user will have a CMS for the apps ,and he will be able to deploy different packages which can be purchased.And he wouldn't need to pay additional fees to developers o add those iAps.Instead it would go online ,and all skus would be stored in a database.And everything would be managed by him.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769635/is-it-possible-to-add-an-in-app-purchase-to-an-app-without-updating-the-app) answer, but i was unable to find the reference on iTunes....

Comment: Is there a programming question in there anywhere?

Comment: Yes there is can the iAp be added without me submitting a new update each time?@PhillipMills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can update IAP items without submitting an update to the app itself.

You have to add the new IAP package to iTunesConnect, but that can be completely separate from the actual app.

Take a read through Apple's Guide to In-App Purchase: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html

Specifically on the 3rd page of that guide:

> If your app has a fixed list of products, such as an in-app purchase to remove ads or enable functionality, embed the list in the app bundle. If the list of product identifiers can change without your app needing to be updated, such as a game that supports additional levels or characters, have your app fetch the list from your server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ,can you find me the exact reference part.I'l accept your answer than. @DonMag

Comment: Thank you tho i red it couple of times i didn't understand it well(article form apple site).Thanks for pointing it out :D