# Can I add a new In-App-Purchase Product without uploading a new App Version?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm new to in-app-purchases for iOS. I want to know:

If I want to add a new product for in-app-purchase, do I have to release a new App version? Or can I add a new IAP - product without updating the app, so that the new product appears in the App?

Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you need to ensure that your app will be able to handle additional products without any need of update.

Also, I've noticed that this question is duplicate. You can check this question as well:

[Is it possible to add an in-app purchase to an app without updating the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769635/is-it-possible-to-add-an-in-app-purchase-to-an-app-without-updating-the-app#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=It%20is%20possible%20as%20long,need%20for%20any%20new%20code.)